Where will be the equilibrium position for the piston?

A piston can slide without friction inside a horizontal cylindrical vessel, which contains an ideal mono-atomic gas. The piston and the inner surface of the cylinder are coated with a thin layer of a perfect heat insulating material. Initially, the piston in equilibrium divides the cylinder into two parts A and B, which are not necessarily equal. The temperatures of the gases in both the parts are equal. Now, the piston is held in its initial position and the gas in part A is supplied some amount of heat, then the piston is released. What will the piston do in its subsequent motion?


I thought that the piston will show an oscillatory motion with a decreasing amplitude and eventually stop at an equilibrium position to the right of the initial position as due to supply of heat equilibrium position should have had shifted to right
But the answers states that it will show an oscillatory motion with a decreasing amplitude and eventually comes to rest at the initial position.
This makes me wonder the mechanism of transfer of heat and the related change in internal energy due to the initial constraint on the motion of piston. And also the fact that despite being in an equilibrium state initially the piston did start a damped oscillation. I think that the motion of piston is going against the fundamentals of motion physics. I want to make sure if I am right or if there is something i am missing or unaware of

I can understand the part about the damped oscillation, but it is unlikely that the piston will arrive at its initial location..

Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question and so allowed by policy.

@gandalf61 I think maybe by changing the way of expressing the problem solved the issue as I also think that it is a relevant question but I don't know how to rephrase it

If there is no friction, there cannot be any damping. Your question seems to be self-contradictory.

It depends on your assumptions. In the ideal quasistatic regime, all collisions are elastic and the entire system exchanges neither heat nor work with the surroundings. Therefore, energy is conserved and there is no damping. The piston will oscillate indefinitely.
Each side undergoes adiabatic processes. Suppose initially, $P_1{V_1}^\gamma = a$ and $P_2{V_2}^\gamma = b$. Then, assuming the piston mass to be unity, we have
$$\ddot{x}=A(P_1-P_2)=A^{1-\gamma}\left(\frac{a}{x^\gamma}-\frac{b}{(L-x)^\gamma}\right)$$
where $x$ is the position, $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the container and $L$ is the length of the container. It can be readily shown that this equation of motion is consistent with (and can also be derived from) conservation of energy. Below is a plot of a sample solution numerically computed using the RK4 method with step size $0.01$.

However, in the more realistic case, there will be a damping force due to pressure differences within each gas which act as drag. It is still true that each gas is adiabatic but there is an additional resistive term. I do not believe that the piston, in general, returns to the starting position. Instead, it will tend to reach the position that maximizes entropy. Below is a plot starting with volume and pressure ratios of 1:3 and 1.5:1. Notice how it does not return to the starting position of 0.25, but rather the midpoint of the two extrema.

